# WSO2APIM Gateway replica syncing delay

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I deployed Distributed WSO2 APIM (2.6.0 - Pattern 2) IS as KM setup in Kubernetes. In my setup there are multiple replicas in the API Gateway deployment.

If the token is generated through the replica 1 of API gateway , the replica 2 takes a significant time to sync with the replica 1 and get to know that a token is generated by replica 1. 
So If I send a request to the replica 2 with the token generated in replica 1, it will show that the token doesn't exist. But after few minutes If I do the same and send the same request to replica 2 it will work without issue because replica 2 is synced with replica 1 at that time and know that the token is generated by replica 1.

Comment: The token is written to the database by the KM node. I assume you don't have database replicas in your setup.

Comment: and what's the exact error message you see in the 2nd gateway?

Comment: @Bee There is no database replica. all the Gateway containers are connected to same database. and the errors are as follows. **Identity Server** `ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid Access Token. Access token is not ACTIVE.` **Gateway** `WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials`